# Entropy change of an irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics

I know that there's a lot of questions about this subject but I couldn't find specifically what I want to ask so here it is:

One of the consequences of Clausius's theorem is the fact that for any transformation we have $dS\geq\delta Q/T $

my question is if my system goes through an irreversible process then do I get $dS>\delta Q/T $ or equality is also possible?

thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The infinitesimal form of Clausius' theorem is

$$dS = \frac{\delta Q}{T} \ \ \ \text{(reversible process)}$$

$$dS > \frac{\delta Q}{T} \ \ \ \text{(irreversible process)}$$

So yes, for an irreversible process you have to take the $>$ sign.

For a proof, see for example E. Fermi, [*Thermodynamics*](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/452/Dover%20Publications%20-%20Thermodynamics%20-%20Enrico%20Fermi%20(1936).pdf), par 13.

Comment: We should note that, in the Fermi reference, he is careful to point out that the T in these equations is not the system temperature, but rather the temperature of the reservoirs that the system is in contact with.  Of course, for a reversible process, there is no difference, but for an irreversible process there is.  The T in these equation should be taken as the temperature at the system interface with the surroundings across which heat transfer is occurring.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Absolutely. Thank you for the clarification.