# When is ${d}\,Q=T\,dS$ not true?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Why is the first T differentiated from the second in  $T\,\frac{{\rm d}\,Q}{T}$ ?

So why do we use a product to express this and not just  ${d}\,Q$  , which goes hand in hand with the cases where $dS>\frac{{\rm d}\,Q}{T}$.

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149579) approaches my want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267634/

Answer (score 1):

The relation is true only for reversible process

$$T\mathrm dS =đq_\textrm{
rev}\;.$$

The Second Law of Thermodynamics provides the general result:

$$\mathrm dS \ge \frac{đq}T\tag 1$$

Let's delve a bit more in this.

Let a system be taken between from its initial state to a certain final state separately by reversibly and then irreversibly; since internal energy is a state function and thus is only concerned  with the final and initial states, its increment would be same in both processes viz:

\begin{align}\,\mathrm dE_\textrm{rev} &= \mathrm dE_\textrm{irrev}\\ \implies \textrm{đ} q_\textrm{rev} - \textrm{đ} w_\textrm{rev} &=\textrm{đ} q_\textrm{irrev}- \textrm{đ} w_\textrm{irrev}\\ \implies  T\mathrm dS- \textrm{đ} w_\textrm{rev} &=\textrm{đ} q_\textrm{irrev}- \textrm{đ} w_\textrm{irrev}\tag 2\;.\end{align}

Now, $S$ is a state function and hence its change only depends on the final and initial states of the system; this means $\mathrm dS$ would be same in both the processes above as the final and initial states are same for both the processes.

So, from $(2)\,,$ we get

$$\mathrm dS= \dfrac{\textrm{đ} q_\textrm{irrev}}{T}+ \dfrac{\left [ \textrm{đ} w_\textrm{rev}-\textrm{đ} w_\textrm{irrev}\right]}{T}\;.\tag 3$$

Since, work done during reversible process is greater than that of irreversible process i.e.  $đw_\textrm{rev}\gt đw_\textrm{irrev},$ from $(3),$ we get

$$\mathrm dS >\frac{đq_\textrm{irrev}}T.\tag 4$$

Comment: How should we know that $ \textrm{đ} w_\textrm{rev}$ and $\textrm{đ} w_\textrm{irrev}$ don't cancel each other?

Comment: @lucas: wait.... I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @lucas: Edited.. re your comment, they are not the same thing that would make them nullify each other.

Comment: How do you prove that *work done during reversible process is greater than that of irreversible process*?

Comment: *work done during reversible process is greater than that of irreversible process* this comes from the second law of thermodynamics. So, you have used the second law of thermodynamics for elaborating itself!

Comment: One thing else, I cannot understand the question body meaning. Is it equal to title?

Comment: @lucas: You have to work against the maximum pressure in reversible process. shall I have to say more?

Comment: I know what you are saying. I didn't ask my first question because of my confusion. I asked it to say you to improve the answer. Your additional explanation (*Let's delve a bit ...*) are not useful. Because as I said you have used the second law of thermodynamics for elaborating itself.

Comment: Of course @lucas, I've taken the second law to be true and showed OP that the relation he mentioned isn't always true; that's it. I'm not seeing any circular reasoning.

Comment: Taking the second law to be true was enough to answer the question. Your additional explanation is a circular reasoning.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Is this because in general there are multiple flows in non-equilibrium systems that influence the microstates?